# Ansible - use external variables in JSON and shell

Tags: ansible

I have a key value dictionary in ansible.
I would like to use the parameter I am getting from the user (on or off) and would like to write down his value in the dictionary.

how I run it:

```
 ansible-playbook -i $INVENTORY -s --extra-vars "switch='on' PLAYBOOKS/add_or_rm.yml
```

the code:

```
 - hosts: docker-first-manager
 vars:
operationMap:
  on: add
  off: rm


 tasks:
  - name: open_kibana_debug_port
    shell:
       docker service update --publish-{{operationMap[switch]}} 5603:5603 my_service
```

Comment: apperntly it does work in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct would be to use when conditions instead. It just seems easier to maintain down the road:

```
  - name: Publish kibana debug port
    shell: docker service update --publish-add 5603:5603 my_service
    when: switch is defined and switch == "on"
  - name: Un-publish kibana debug port
    shell: docker service update --publish-rm 5603:5603 my_service
    when: switch is not defined or switch != "on"
```